# Passing value from a function into a input field

Tags: javascript

Problem: I'm trying to pass a return value from a function into a input field.

I get no errors the field is just blank.

Question: Why is my code not working?

HTML

```
<tr>
<td>Quantity to be dredged</td>
<td><input type="number"  class="" id="shorePipe"></input></td>
</tr>
```

JavaScript

```
var shorePipe = function() {
  var val = 100;
  var val2 = 100;
  var total = val * val2 / 100;
  // return total;
  document.getElementById('shorePipe').value = total;
};
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *readyonly* isn't a valid HTML attribute.

Comment: do you get any errors? also, please read our [ask] page to help you improve the question

Comment: I guess you know it, but you have a typo in readyonly, should be readonly. also, you don't need </input>

Comment: Are you sure you don't have an error in the console? Also, does your code do anything? Or you simply have no result at all?

Comment: Basically, It runs some calculations and returns the sum. however I am working on codepen maybe that;s my problem

Comment: you aren't firing the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your code works perfectly fine (beside `</input>`), the only issue I see here is that you're probably not calling `shorePipe();` once the **DOM is read and ready**.

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/muhane/2/edit?html,output)***

So put your JS right before the closing `</body>` tag

```
<script>
var shorePipe = function() {
  var val = 100;
  var val2 = 100;
  var total = val * val2 / 100;
  // return total;
  document.getElementById('shorePipe').value = total;
};
shorePipe();
</script>

</body>
```

notice also that `</input>` is invalid. `<input>` is in the group of [**void** elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-elements) and should not have a closing tag.

Comment: It's a joke. they are all the same, where's your sense of humor?

Comment: lol I was simply being a bit cheeky. Was meant as an aid for you since you hadn't posted a plunkr/fiddle/bin yet. :)

Comment: @EvanBechtol BTW your jsfiddle does not show that `<script>` is placed right before `</body>` so it's not much of a help. :(

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the function

```
shorePipe();
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2vxdyvgz/

Answer (score 0):

1. Input doesn't need to close itself.
2. Make sure you actually call your JS function somewhere.

I created this JSFiddle for you:
https://jsfiddle.net/pd12edbp/2/

```
<input type="number"  class="" id="shorePipe" readyonly>
```

JS:

```
var shorePipe = function() {
   var val = 100;
   var val2 = 100;
   var total = val * val2 / 100;
   // return total;
   document.getElementById('shorePipe').value = total;
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    shorePipe();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in your original post, you were passing the value to the element with ID shorePipe, and your input had ID avgSubPipe

element ID's have to match. 
ANd, you have to fire the function

the HTML

```
<tr>
<td>Quantity to be dredged</td>
<td><input type="number"  class="" id="avgSubPipe" readonly ></td>
</tr>
```

and the Javascript:

```
var shorePipe = function() {
  var val = 100;
  var val2 = 100;
  var total = val * val2 / 100;
  // return total;
  document.getElementById('shorePipe').value = total;
};

// calling function
shorePipe();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yhz7syhs/1/